# Normalize any URL or path into a standard path syntax

Tags: ruby

I want to take a URL or only a path and strip out everything except the path with a consistent syntax, like not having an ending slash and such.

Examples:

```
'/categories/cameras/'             => '/categories/cameras'
'http://domain.com/products/'      => '/products'
'products'                         => '/products'
'deals/newyears/'                  => '/deals/newyears'
'https://domain.com/'              => '/'
'https://domain.com/terms#refunds' => '/terms'
''                                 => '/'
```

Any ideas how to make a method that does this?

Comment: Translating `domain.com/products` to `/products` causes some trouble—how do you know `domain.com` is a domain name and not a pathname (i.e. why does it not expand to `http://domain.com/domain.com/products`? `domain.com` is a perfectly valid path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
require 'uri'

def standard_path(p)
  path = URI.parse(p).path
  path.insert(0, '/') if (path[0] != '/')
  path.chomp!('/') if (path > '/')
  path
end

[
  '/categories/cameras/',
  'http://domain.com/products/',
  'products',
  'deals/newyears/',
  'https://domain.com/',
  'https://domain.com/terms#refunds',
  '',
].each do |p|
  puts standard_path(p)
end
```

Which outputs:

```
/categories/cameras
/products
/products
/deals/newyears
/
/terms
/
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a rather specific use case. I can't think of anything that would handle this with a single function unless you're willing to write your own.

Generally something like `"products"` is considered to be a relative path, where `"/products"` is a literal path and `"http://example.com/products"` is an absolute URI. Each of these are handled differently in `URI.join`.

I'm not sure how `"domain.com/products"` is interpreted as `"/products"` unless you presume that the first part of the path is not allowed to contain `.`. A rather reaching assumption, but maybe that'll work in your use case.

Here's a snippet that might work:

```
require 'uri'

def remap(path)
  uri = nil

  case (path)
  when %r<^https?://>
    uri = URI.parse(path)
  when %r<^/>
    uri = URI.parse("http://example.com#{path}")
  when %r<^[\w\-]+\.\w+/>
    uri = URI.parse("http://#{path}")
  else
    uri = URI.parse("http://example.com/#{path}")
  end

  uri and uri.path
end
```

I'm not sure why `"/"` would return empty string, as all the others are prefixed with a slash. You could always add in that logic if you prefer, but it seems inconsistent.

Comment: +1. The syntax highlighter seems to really hate your use of “non-standard” literal delimiters, though `:P`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the [Ruby Standard URI library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html)?

```
> require "uri"
 => true 
> URI.parse("/foo").path
 => "/foo" 
> URI.parse("http://google.com/foo").path
 => "/foo" 
> URI.parse("http://google.com").path
 => ""
```

Comment: Except `URI.parse('domain.com/products').path #=> "domain.com/products"`.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. 99% of the job is still done for you with the library. Just wrap it and use a simple regex or something.

Comment: That doesn't normalize at all, try `URI.parse("/foo/")` it'll return `/foo/` not `/foo`, and that's just one case.